# Suddenly can't read from database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm been tearing my hair out for the past hour trying to work out why certain functions have always been returning false bools when I was certain the determinants were correct.

So, as debuggers do I abstracted further and further out testing all variables until I got to the point where I was actually testing the bloody database connection.

I can connect to my database but every single query sent to it always returns false. I'm so confused. How can this be wrong?

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:db=privatechat;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
var_dump($db);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `accounts`");
var_dump($stmt);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
var_dump($row);
```

The result:

```
object(PDO)#1 (0) { } object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(24) "SELECT * FROM `accounts`" } bool(false)
```

This is the crazy part... when I connect to another local project it's fine!?

Here's a screenshot of my DB and tables:

[image: Database and table]

I just realised as I submitted this question that "db=" should be "dbname="

Good grief! :)

Comment: What is the actual MySQL error that you get?

Comment: It's ok I just realised the PDO string is wrong. I put "db=" instead of "dbname="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `dbname=privatechat` in your DSN.

Comment: Thank you. I'm forever falling for these tiny details!

Answer (score 1):

The PDO connection string should be "mysql:dbname=privatechat" I missed the 'name' part! Woops!

Comment: Hmmm I placed a try catch around this in another document and it didn't throw an exception. Which is why I assumed the DSN was ok. Could this be a bug?